# Spiral traversal of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm working through a coding problem and writing a function that will traverse a nested array in a snail-like pattern (example [here](http://www.haan.lu/files/2513/8347/2456/snail.png)).

For example, given input of `[[1,2,3], [8,9,4], [7,6,5]]`, the function should output `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`.

Within my main function, I created 4 functions to traverse the array in all directions. At each step I push the value at the current grid position and check a flag array to determine if the next position has been visited yet.

I have two problems:

1. I couldn't clone the array passed as an argument successfully. Even if I used `array.slice(0)`, the new `flagsArray` seems to be functioning as a pointer to `array` and when I modify `flagsArray`, the changes are reflected in `array`. Why is that?

My approach to cloning seems to work when I run this test:

```
var array = [0, 1];
var array_clone = array.slice(0);
array_clone[2] = 3;
console.log(array); // No changes to array
```

2. I get `flagsArray[(i + 1)] is undefined` error while executing traverseDown(). This looks like trying to read an index beyond `flagsArray`. But if I check for `flagsArray[i + 1][j] === false && i < flagsArray.length` in a `while` loop, shouldn't the loop just stop once it tries to read beyond the array? For one because `flagsArray[flags.Array.length]` would be undefined, therefore not equal to `false`, and the other reason being that I check also for `i` being within the `flagsArray` range.

Here's my function:

```
snail = function(array) {
  console.log(array);
  var output = [];

  var flagsArray = array.slice(0);

  // Populating flagsArray with false values
  // False = index not visited yet
  for (var i = 0; i < flagsArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < flagsArray[i].length; j++) {
      flagsArray[i][j] = false;
    }
  }
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;

    var traverseRight = function() {
    while (flagsArray[i][j + 1] === false && j < flagsArray[i].length) {
      console.log(flagsArray[i][j].length + 'Traversing right Index traversed: [' + i + '][' + j +'] Flag before: ' + flagsArray[i][j] + 'Element pushed: ' + array[i][j]);
      output.push(array[i][j]);
      flagsArray[i][j] = true;
      j++;
    } 
  }

  var traverseDown = function() {
    while (flagsArray[i + 1][j] === false && i < flagsArray.length) {
      console.log('Traversing Down Index traversed: [' + i + '][' + j +'] Flag before: ' + flagsArray[i][j] + 'Element pushed: ' + array[i][j]);
      output.push(array[i][j]);
      flagsArray[i][j] = true;
      i++;
    }
  }

  var traverseLeft = function() {
    while (array[i][j - 1] === false && j >= 0) {
      console.log('Traversing left Index traversed: [' + i + '][' + j +'] Flag before: ' + flagsArray[i][j] + 'Element pushed: ' + array[i][j]);
      output.push(array[i][j]);
      flagsArray[i][j] = true;
      j--;
    }
  }

  var traverseUp = function() {
    while (array[i][j] === false && j >= 0) {
      console.log('Traversing Up Index traversed: [' + i + '][' + j +'] Flag before: ' + flagsArray[i][j] + 'Element pushed: ' + array[i][j]);
      output.push(array[i][j]);
      flagsArray[i][j] = true;
      i--;
    }
  }

  while (flagsArray[i][j + 1] === false) {
    traverseRight();
    traverseDown();
    traverseLeft();
    traverseUp();
  } 
  return output;
}

console.log(snail([[1,2,3],[8,9,4],[7,6,5]]));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Question 1

> I couldn't clone the array passed as an argument successfully. Even if I used `array.slice(0)`, the new `flagsArray` seems to be functioning as a pointer to `array` and when I modify `flagsArray`, the changes are reflected in `array`. Why is that?

It's because you have a two-dimensional array and you've only made a copy of the outer array. Each of its elements is an original inner array.

To make a deep copy of `array` that we can manipulate without altering the original, we must copy each of the inner arrays:

```
var flags = new Array(array.length);
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
  flags[i] = array[i].slice();
}
```

(Note: I have taken the liberty of renaming `flagsArray` to `flags`. Also note that `slice()` can be called without an argument to copy the array starting from index 0.)

We can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do the same thing more concisely:

```
var flags = array.map(function (subarray) {
  return subarray.slice();
});
```

But there's no point to copying the array values if we immediately overwrite them with `false`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < flags.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < flags[i].length; j++) {
    flags[i][j] = false;
  }
}
```

We can delete that double loop if we put `false` values into the flag array while we're making it:

```
var flags = array.map(function (subarray) {
  return subarray.map(function () {
    return false;
  });
});
```

## Question 2

> I get `flagsArray[(i + 1)] is undefined` error while executing traverseDown(). This looks like trying to read an index beyond `flagsArray`. But if I check for `flagsArray[i + 1][j] === false && i < flagsArray.length` in a `while` loop, shouldn't the loop just stop once it tries to read beyond the array?

No, JavaScript does nothing to prevent out-of-bounds array access. What's happening in the line

```
while (flagsArray[i + 1][j] === false && i < flagsArray.length) {
```

is that `flagsArray[i + 1]` evaluates to `undefined` because `i + 1` is beyond the last element of the array. Then you try to look up `[j]`, and the program crashes because `undefined` has no properties.

You don't even get around to evaluating `i < flagsArray.length`. Besides, that test wouldn't prevent an invalid index because if `i` is the index of the last element, `flagsArray[i + 1]` is out of bounds.

## General observations

This test has two problems:

```
while (flagsArray[i][j + 1] === false && j < flagsArray[i].length) {
```

First, you're neglecting to check the array index before accessing the array. Second, you're not testing the right value. You should test `j + 1` before accessing `flagsArray[i][j + 1]`:

```
while (j + 1 < flagsArray[i].length && flagsArray[i][j + 1] === false) {
```

There are similar problems with the three other tests.

As an alternative to writing four functions, I recommend that you write the traversal logic once and make it depend on an `orientation` variable that has a value from `0` through `3`. The only thing that differs with the direction of movement is the amount by which you increment the grid indices. You can look up these incrementation values in a pair of arrays with `orientation` as the array index.

The incrementation arrays look like this:

```
var dr = [ -1, 0, 1, 0 ],  // North, east, south, west.
    dc = [ 0, 1, 0, -1 ];
```

Given a grid position `r, c`, you can calculate the next position like this:

```
var R = r + dr[orientation],
    C = c + dc[orientation];
```

The following snippet demonstrates this approach.

```js
function print(line) {
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += line + '<br><br>';
}

var snail = function(array) {
  var result = [];

  var flags = array.map(function (subarray) {
    return subarray.map(function () {
      return false;
    });
  });
  print(JSON.stringify(array));

  var numRows = flags.length,
      numCols = flags[0].length,
      numElements = numRows * numCols,
      dr = [ -1, 0, 1, 0 ],  // North, east, south, west.
      dc = [ 0, 1, 0, -1 ],
      r = 0,
      c = 0,
      orientation = 1;       // Start heading east.

  var count = 0;

  while (result.length < numElements) {
    result.push(array[r][c]);
    flags[r][c] = true;
    var R = r + dr[orientation],  // Calculate the next grid position.
        C = c + dc[orientation];
    if (R >= 0 && R < numRows && C >= 0 && C < numCols && !flags[R][C]) {
      r = R;                      // If the position is valid, go ahead.
      c = C;
    } else {
      orientation = (orientation + 1) % 4;
      r = r + dr[orientation];    // Otherwise, turn clockwise and recalculate.
      c = c + dc[orientation];
    }
  }

  return result;
}

window.onload = function () {
  print(snail([ [1, 2, 3],
                [8, 9, 4],
                [7, 6, 5] ]));
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="message"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

## Spiral Array (ES6)

Try this:

```
function spiral(array) {
    const matrix = [...array];
    const arr = [];

    while (matrix.length) {
        arr.push(
            ...matrix.shift(),
            ...matrix.map(a => a.pop()),
            ...matrix.pop().reverse(),
            ...matrix.map(a => a.shift()).reverse()
        );
    }
    return arr;
}
```